# login to multiple play store console accounts in different browsers

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

My task is to manage multiple play store console accounts.
Can i login to multiple console accounts in same laptop but different browsers?
I heard that you should not login to same computer for different accounts?

Help needed?

Thanks